# Is there any custom rom which can be installed on any android device

Tags: custom-roms

My question is, whether there are any custom rom's available which can be installed on any device or the rom's are just intended for a specific device. I always read that like custom rom for galaxy note 3, for s4 like that.. are there any roms available which can be installed on any device... if not, can any one explain why we need to design rom's for a specific model.

Comment: Because although Device Tree is a thing, it's still not very popular.

Comment: For the last part of your question, see [Why are there not generic phone installers?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/63630/12442)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each model has different hardware, which requires specific drivers. This is why each device has a separate ROM. This is different from desktop OSs because of the disk space constraints. If a ROM was made to support all devices, the drivers would eat all your available storage, and more.

Comment: so, the phone manufactures also optimize the android OS for every device.. same OS cant be used.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Each ROM, custom or stock, is designed and optimized for that device.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, well can we use a rom basing on the hardware details.. like my note3 has exynos processor .. and alcatel one touch has mediatek's octa core version ... i can easily find the roms for my note3.. but can i use a rom which supports mediatek's octa core on my alcatel device..

Comment: In theory you could, as long as the hardware configuration is exactly the same. But there's a lot more to the configuration than the SoC (Radio, storage configuration, display, external connections...), which meand you'd have to edit the ROM yourself. And since this site deals with end-user questions, not development questions, you'd be better off asking this on StackOverflow or XDA.

Comment: Thank you, it seems i have to study a bit about how these things work..