# Is it possible to install Nexus factory reset images on other Android devices

Tags: updates, factory-reset, onda-tablet

The device I want to install Nexus onto is the Onda VI10 tablet.

I found some Nexus factory images [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images), and I would like to install them. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to  Android Enthusiasts! This happens to be a question frequently asked on our site. Have you tried our on-site search? See [How do I search?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/searching) for help using it. See e.g. [Why are there not generic phone OS installers?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/63630/16575) / [Is there any custom rom which can be installed on any android device](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/75344/16575)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### *Short answer:*

No.

### *Long answer:*

Nexus factory images, as so kindly implied by their name, are complete snapshots of the software installed on a Nexus device prior to leaving the factory.

Due to the device-specific nature of Android, e.g. it needs specific drivers for it to run on any one given device, it is generally impossible (or illogical, as it seems) to run a build of Android for a specific device on another device.