# Installing flash images on an unrecommended device

Tags: rom-flashing, samsung

I want to install the Nexus Hammerhead flash image on my Samsung Galaxy S Duos. Is this possible and if so is it safe?

Comment: Short answer: NO. Long answer: Noooooooooooooooooo! If you are flashing an image / ROM on a device it must be for the **exact** device **and** model, otherwise you will have a shiny paperweight!

Comment: @RossC Isn't that the answer to the question? Maybe adding a link to: [Why are there not generic phone OS installers?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/63630/16575) / [Why is it that Android still can't be installed as regular OS?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20364/16575) Though basically, this is a dupe of a dupe: [Is there any custom rom which can be installed on any android device](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/75344/16575) even...