# Does Lineage OS 16 runs on Nokia 6.1?

Tags: lineageos, nokia-6

I am looking to find if the Nokia 6.1 is able to run Lineage OS 16. I didnt find a Nokia section in the [official list of supported device](https://download.lineageos.org/). I looked online and find this list from [thedroidguru](https://thedroidguru.com/lineageos-16supported-devices-and-release-date/) (same list on [alldroidtips](https://alldroidtips.com/lineage-os-16/#List_Of_NokiaDevices_Getting_Lineage_OS_16)):

> List Of Nokia Devices Getting Lineage OS 16
>
> Nokia, or HMD Global, has already maintained a nice record when it
>   comes to providing Android updates. Though these devices did not
>   receive any support from LineageOS 15, it is expected that LineageOS
>   16 would support the Nokia 8, Nokia 6 2017, Nokia 1, Nokia 2, Nokia 3,
>   Nokia 5.

As far as I know, the Nokia 6.1 is the name of the Nokia 6 2018. Is this list accurate? If the Nokia 6 2017 can run the rom, the 6.1 should be able to do so, shouldn't it? So, Does Lineage OS 16 runs on Nokia 6.1?

Comment: Kind of related: [Why are there not generic phone OS installers?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/63630/44325)

Answer (score 3):

Well, nobody knows which devices will be supported for LineageOS 16 because each device's maintainer(s) (developer(s)) are different.

LineageOS team never maintains a list of devices supported for LineageOS 15.1 or 16 etc.
But they have a devices list for which they support any of the LineageOS version:
https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/

But that's not all. The actual official builds come very late because of many factors.
For example, the lineage16.0 branch is almost ready but there is no OFFICIAL LineageOS 16 build available from LineageOS team or any device maintainer.

But if you see the [LineageOS 16](https://www.cyanogenmods.org/lineageos-16-supported-devices-list-and-downloads-android-pie-9-0/) builds available UNOFFICIALLY, you will find many devices. This is not an official source but more accurate as it is maintained by me.
I hand pick all of the available builds to accumulate at one place.

Similar to LineageOS 16, I have an [OFFICIAL LineageOS 15.1](https://www.cyanogenmods.org/official-lineageos-15-1-download-supported-devices-list-oreo-8-1/#List_of_Available_Download_links_for_OFFICIAL_Lineage_OS_151_ROM_based_on_Android_Oreo_81_for_all_devices_by_Android_OEMs_Arranged_Alphabetically) page where you will find all such OFFICIAL builds.
I will continue to maintain an OFFICIAL LineageOS 16 page when the builds will be available.

Coming to your question, as of now I did not see any builds available for Nokia 6.1. You may follow my LineageOS 16 link, where I do update the page almost on daily basis. You will find the build once it is available from a dev.

Answer (score 3):

There are only unofficial builds of Lineage for the Nokia 6.1. Else you can try out a few GSIs. Since the bootloader is only unlockable via unofficial methods, and there are not enough Nokia users with unlocked bootloaders, the chances for an official LOS support are super thin.