# New Android version for Acer DA220HQL

Tags: updates

I have got the following android model (Acer DA220HQL) with  Android Ice Cream installed (Android 4.0.4). Unfortunately this version is quite outdated nowadays and all android apps  do not work. I would like to know, if there is any new official Android version or even a custom android rom that would be compatible with this specific model (image attached for better assistance) and which one.

That would help me a lot!

[image]

Regards

Comment: It seems there's no official update for this device. I also noticed that you have been asking this on many forums without success. I'm afraid if there's no custom ROM found on XDA until now, then it seems impossible to create one (I noticed that [the ROM developer needed the device tree source](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=45480073&postcount=74) which seems unavailable). I'm skeptical about the blog that says it's possible to update to Android 6 though... sorry :(

Comment: I just saw that same blog for update to android 6 and I would like to ask if it is possible and also if exists such version of that particular device. I have posted only to acer community forum where I got no reply and android central forum where they told me that I might find one android version, but it does not worth the effort to install it. Asking this trustworthy forum if android 6 is supported by this device? Regards

Comment: Actually, forget that blog... the download links are already dead, and the blog contains many similar posts just with the device name changed, the reviews are also fake... the only hope was someone from the XDA forum *speculated* that it might be possible to create a custom ROM based on Android 4.1/4.2, but then nothing heard anymore. I'm really afraid that there's no alternative since [each Android ROM has to be made specifically for each device](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/63630/44325)...