# Android PC linux installation on Acer DA220HQL

Tags: android-pc

I have got an android PC (Acer DA220HQL) running Android 4.0.4 with the following [specifications](https://www.cnet.com/products/acer-da220hql-android-pc/) and i would like to know if there is any installation procedure step by step to install other (linux-based) OS such as Zorin OS lite as many Google android tablets are locked from installing other OS.

That would help me a lot!

Regards

Comment: as for all embedded devices only if someone built a ROM especially for that device. there are solutions to run chroot linux on top of android, but that tablet has very low hardware ressources. so the answer is no

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have found other alternative such as bliss OS (https://blissos.org) that might be a fit as this PC tablet has got x86 and ARM architecture ? Is there any safe step by step installation procedure because it is locked from installing other OS. That would help me a lot!

Comment: blissos won't work too

Comment: Low hardware resources or lock installation. If there is a safe installation at least I want to try it before get rid of it. Thanks.

Comment: if you want to understand **why** it is impossible read that around ~ 20 links starting from [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226963) (in short: embedded device is completely different from PC)

Comment: please refer to comments from [Andrew T.♦](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/230329/new-android-version-for-acer-da220hql#comment301971_230329)

Comment: https://zorinos.com/help/system-requirements

Comment: [How to boot Ubuntu persistent live USB on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220678/218526)

Comment: The device has an "ARM Cortex A" CPU, thus all x86 based OS (blissos.org, ...) do not work.