# Custom boot image

Tags: hardware, xiaomi

I have a smartphone (Xiaomi mido) with a corrupted eMMC, but it seems I can load a boot image into it and run it. I would like to experiment with low-level programming in Rust, such as the display and camera. I found the source code for mido, but I don't understand it at all. Tons of code I don't understand. Googling without success. So that the question can be answered objectively, you can answer that what I'm doing is impossible or stupid. Can I at least run `Hello World` on my smartphone hardware?

Comment: Related reading: [Bootloader/BIOS, flashing ROM and correlated risks. Why Android devices are more brickable than PCs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/205072/3573), and [Why are there not generic phone OS installers?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/63630/3573)