# Are there any device that allow updating Android OS out of the box?

Tags: rooting, updates

**Can you get a phone where you can update the system without the need to root your phone?**
I've never done this myself (rooting) and for my new phone, I want to have something that will use Google Play Store and that I will be able to update the system myself. My current phone is more than 5 years old (Xiomi Redmi 4x) and it looks like Xiomi put a time bomb to slow the phone down (sometimes there is even a delay when you tap the input box to open the virtual keyboard). It suddenly slowed down when about 5 years passed. I'm not 100% sure if they did but I would not be surprised.

And another question: **can you update the OS on every phone?**

Can you suggest something that will allow me to use Google Play and have up to date system?

Comment: stock android ROM for sure will tell you once update is available. rooting will break OTA updates

Comment: @alecxs but I'm asking when a new version of Android came out. Like I Have Android 7 and I want to update to Android 8. I can do that with any Linux distro without the need to reinstall the system, I use an automated update to the new version. I would like to have the same on Android.

Comment: Android is not released, it is launched. every phone model receive updates from manufacturer especially compiled for this model. that's the main difference between OS distros and firmware updates for [embedded devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_on_embedded_systems). it's up to OEMs decision how long they support old phone models. typically end of life is after 2 years

Comment: @alecxs so there is no Android version that can have updates (I mean upgrade to the next version) and you need to throw a phone away because the manufacturer doesn't support it after 2 years? This is such a waste. No wonder there are more Gmail installs than people on the planet.

Comment: as I said phones receive upgrades to next Android version on vendors decision. Samsung or OnePlus maintain old devices up to 5 years. some OEMs (such as Xiaomi) allow bootloader unlocking and provide kernel source code, what makes you free to compile more recent [AOSP](https://forum.xda-developers.com/f/xiaomi-redmi-4x-roms-kernels-recoveries-other.6958/?order=post_date&direction=desc) your own

Comment: Your "time bomb" that slows down the phone is simply the fact that the apps are getting bigger over time and require more RAM - more than your phone provides so apps have to be frequently stopped and restarted which takes significant time. Another good vendor for long term software and hardware support is Fair Phone.

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [Why are there not generic phone OS installers?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/63630/44325)