# is it possible to install 6.0 marshmellow on a non nexus

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, installation

im new to this community but is it possible to install android 6.0 on a non-nexus phone with a universal install image

if not please tell

Comment: It is definitely possible to install Android 6.0 on a non-Nexus device (there are many other devices running Android 6). But there's no such thing as an "universal install image". Also see: [Why are there not generic phone OS installers?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/63630/16575) / [Why must my device be compatible with a certain ROM before I flash it to my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/60022/16575) / [Can you install a generic ROM on any device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/82359/16575)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, the answer is NO, unless the phone you are using is Nexus or is the exact copy of Nexus (with the same specs, no changes at all).

The factory images that Android releases for Nexus are optimised for Nexus devices only and won't work on others. Trying to fastboot flash such images might brick your device for good.